# How to align text from two different divs

Tags: html, css

I have following html code

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Title text</h1>
        <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <h2>Right title</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

And css

```
#main {
    width: 230px
}
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
}
#right {
    float: right;
    width: 80px;
}
#right h2 {
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

I want `Right title` to be aligned with top of red square. The problem is that `Title text` can be long and text will be placed on two lines.
Can I achieve this using only css?

http://jsfiddle.net/6Rpkh/312/

Comment: What part do you want aligned exactly?

Comment: @changer: Red square has dynamic dimension? Title text must be grouped with red square?

Answer (score 0):

I change CSS and structure of html, i put div `#right,#right1` into the content and set `margin-top` negative
CSS

```
#content, #content1 {
    float: left;
    width: 185px;
}
#right, #right1 {
    float: right;
    width: 80px;
    margin-top:-105px;
}
#right h2, #right1 h2 {
    margin-top: 0em;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            <h1>Title text</h1>
            <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red"></div>
        <div id="right">
            <h2>Right title</h2>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <br style="clear: both"><br><br>

    <div id="main1">
        <div id="content1">
            <h1>Very long title text on two lines</h1>
            <div style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red"></div>
         <div id="right1">
            <h2>Right title</h2>
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Rpkh/313/

Answer (score 0):

maybe remake the structure to have 3 sections: header, left and content, instead of left and content only:

http://jsfiddle.net/78Lczwoq/

```
.square {
    float: left;
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.header {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.media {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
    float: left;
}
.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to modify your html. Check the below fiddle:

```
#main, #main1 {
    width: 230px
}
#content, #content1 {
    width: 150px;
}
#right, #right1 {
    float: right;
    width: 80px;
}
#right h2, #right1 h2, .box {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Rpkh/314/)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works perfect as per you requirement.

## HTML

```
    <div id="main">
               <div id="inner_container">
                   <p class="top_title">Some long title here it automatically adjusts</p>
                      <div class="sq_box"> 
                   </div>
                   <div class="right_title">
                       hello
                   </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

## CSS

```
                    #main{
                width:400px;
                height:200px;
            }
            #inner_container{
                width:100%;
                height:auto;
            }
            p.top_title{
                width: 100px; 
                word-wrap: break-word;
            }
            .sq_box{
                width:100px;
                float:left;
                height:100px;
                background-color:red;
            }
            .right_title{
                float:left;
                margin-left:10%;
            }
```

[JSFILDLE demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6Rpkh/315/)

> This adjusts itself no need to care about any margin.. its robust ..